# List subtype casting for Combining >10 retrofit calls together with rxjava2

Tags: android, list, retrofit2, rx-java2

I'd like to call my API endpoints from my mobile android app.

I usually use zip operator for waiting the last operation to be completed, but i have more than 10 retrofit calls to process and the maximum function in input to the zip operator i found is Function9.

I tried to pass an iterable instead but i have an issue about the types inside the emitter:

```
@GET("/endpoint/A")
Single<List<A>> getA();

@GET("/endpoint/B")
Single<List<B>> getB();

@GET("/endpoint/C")
Single<List<C>> getC();

....
```

Every data type A,B,C... implements an interface Sample such that i pass a List to zip operator:

```
List<Single<List<Sample>>> callsList = new ArrayList<>();
callsList.add(apiService.getA()); // error, expected Single<List<Sample>
```

i tried to force a cast but didnt work neither

My goal is to use the iterable in order to achieve something like this:

```
Single.zip(callsList, new Function<Object[], BundledData>() {
        @Override
        public BundledData apply(Object[] objects) throws Exception {
            return new BundledData(...);
        }
    })
```

So i'm asking for your help for:

- Resolving the type incompatibility
- Passing the correct data format to the apply function

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't cast this way . Because `Single<List<A>>`  is not subtype of `Single<List<Sample>>` . Here `A` is subtype of `Sample` but Single>`is not subtype of`Single>`.

Let me give you a simple example :

```
    List<Number> listA = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> listB  = new ArrayList<>();

    listA = listB; // this line is not valid.
```

But this is valid:

```
    Number number = 10;
    Integer integer = 20;

    number = integer;
```

Because `Integer` is a subtype of `Number`. and  `listA = listB;` is not valid because `listB` is not subtype of `listA`.

But still you can cast it you have to use `Wildcard` .

Using wildcard will be like :

```
    List<? extends Number> listA = new ArrayList<>();
    List<? extends Integer> listB  = new ArrayList<>();

    listA = listB;
```

Now `List<? extends Integer>` is a subtype of `List<? extends Number>`

To make casting possible we need a common parent for both `List<Number>` and `List<Integer>`  and `List<?>` is common parent.

This is nicely explain in [official doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html)

[image]

> Although Integer is a subtype of Number, `List<Integer>` is not a subtype of `List<Number>` and, in fact, these two types are not related. The common parent of `List<Number>` and `List<Integer>` is `List<?>`.
>
> In order to create a relationship between these classes so that the
>   code can access Number's methods through List's elements, use
>   an upper bounded wildcard:

Your case is same. You need to use upper bounded wildcard.

```
List< Single< ? extends List< ? extends Sample> > > callsList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Hope this helps you.